# Why was my "very low quality" flag declined?

Tags: support, faq, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29407/how-to-imitate-this-search-page-style/29422#29422) as "very low quality" (which it is). The content of the question is the following:

> So, I'm looking to create a search page with similar functionality to [this one](http://www.indieonthemove.com/venues), where you can organize by location and then sort by other information. For node location data I'm using the location module. I'm wondering whether I should use Views with exposed filters, Search API, or something else. I'm happy to learn modules, but I'd rather not spend a lot of time learning/figuring one out that I won't end up using.

The content of the answer is the following:

> This looks like something for views

My flag was declined with this reason:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I feel like the point has been missed here; the whole *reason* I flagged it was so that it would be brought to a mod's attention, and that they can intervene and delete the answer (which I am not able to do). The answer simply isn't good enough for a Stack Exchange site and should be removed.

Why does a flag for "very low quality" exist if I'm not allowed to use it on Drupal Answers? If that flag reason is not in fact used to flag low quality answers (as I have used it for in this instance), than what is it for?

N.B. I use this exact reason to flag similar answers on the main Stack Overflow site all the time, and I've never had a single one declined, or even disputed, so I know my reasoning is correct per the Stack Exchange rules/ethos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A post should be flagged as "very low quality" when it's not clear what it means, at the point that editing it is not even possible. The flag should not be used, for example, when:

- The OP doesn't capitalize *I* when referring to the first person singular.
- The OP doesn't use the correct punctuation, and writes run-on sentences.
- The OP writes a verb using the third person singular when it should not be used (e.g. *writes* instead of *write*).
- The OP doesn't use the correct tense for a verb.

If a single post is very low quality then:

- If it is a question, it should be voted to be closed (or flagged to be closed for the same reason)
- If it is an answer, it should be flagged as *not an answer*

The *very low quality* flag should be used when the user keeps posting low quality posts. The flag is a flag for removal for the post, and (eventually) for the user who posted it.
It should not be used to mean, for example, "I cannot be bothered to edit this post because the user keeps writing *i* instead of *I*." or when a user posts a wrong answer because misunderstanding the question being asked; in such cases, a down-vote is sufficient. Once an answer has a negative score, 3 votes from 20k users delete it.

Flags should not used for technical inaccuracies, as moderators (to whom the flags are directed) should not be called to judge the accuracy of an answer.

If the moderators find evidence of any problem with that post, and they take action, the flag is automatically marked as helpful; this happens, for example, when the *very low quality* flag is used for spam, for a comment that has been posted as answer, or a completely different question that has been post as answer. If the moderators don't find any evidence of problems with the post, they will probably decline the flag.
In any case, even if flags are automatically handled, the *very low quality* flag should not be used for replacement of other flags or other actions, such as closing an off-topic question.

References: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114003/flagged-as-low-quality-declined-but-i-still-think-the-question-was-low-quality), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/140449), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111108/what-kind-of-answer-should-be-flagged-as-very-low-quality-but-not-flagged-as), [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous).